# Design guideline for pads for receiving castellated half holes on the other board

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Many tutorials on castellated half-holes are for designing the half-holes themselves ([OSH Park](https://docs.oshpark.com/tips+tricks/castellation/), and [Danny Staple's question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279893/pcb-design-how-long-should-pads-be-made-to-hand-solder-half-vias)). There are very little documents on how to design the pads for **receiving** the castellated daughter boards. In [cholz's question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440765/surface-mount-adapter-pcb-with-castellated-holes), the answer refers to a [SparkFun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-solder-castellated-mounting-holes/all). However, the tutorial only concerns about soldering and there is no specification to the surface mount pads.

Therefore, what are the design guidelines for the those pads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all footprint-related questions, it depends on the specifics:

- What is the placement method? Pick'n'place or manual placement?
- Reflow or hand soldering?
- Density requirements on the host PCB?
- Leaded or lead-free solder?
- etc. etc.

To get started, I would recommend modifying the guidance from the ESP32 datasheet [here](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32e_esp32-wroom-32ue_datasheet_en.pdf) - look at their castel-to-hole size ratios and modify from there to suit your particular module. The ESP32 footprint would be a standard footprint suitable for most production processes. Then iteratively improving that if that doesn't meet your needs in practice.